# Make blocks of text invisible only if said so

Tags: text, text-manipulation

Is there any command which allows me to make some blocks of text invisible only if initially I said so?

I.e., I would like to mark some lines throughout the text that would **only appear in the compiled pdf if in the beggining of the document I said something like: "those blocks of text ON";** and I don't want them to appear if I said something like "those blocks of text OFF".

The purpose of this is to generate two different documents: **one with more deitailed information and another one without those details**.

Note that this is **not the same** as the phantom or comment commands.

Comment: Should the space of such blocks be preserved ? Which documentclass do you use? Does these blocks contain things like labels which are necessary in the remaining text?

Comment: No, the space should not be preserved, i.e., when I say that I don't want those lines to appear, I really don't want any trace of that text in the compiled document.
Also: these blocks of text which I'm refering to are simple text lines: no labels, no pics, etc.

Comment: I think that the comment package is perfect for this... https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/comment/comment.pdf

Comment: Be aware that making the text "invisible" is not the same as making it "not there." If the text in question has private content. some methods for making it "invisible" will still leave the text in the PDF, where it can be extracted. The accepted answer is OK, as is use of `comment` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to do something like this in the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\additionalInfo}[1]{#1}
```

and then put all of those lines into that macro like this:

```
\additionalInfo{I am additional}
```

If you don't want the lines to show up just replace above macro definition with

```
\newcommand{\additionalInfo}[1]{}
```

Not as elegant as the other answers but in my opinion the simplest solution...

---

```
\documentclass{article}

% switch comment to disable additional info
\newcommand{\additionalInfo}[1]{#1}
% \newcommand{\additionalInfo}[1]{}

\begin{document}
I am always here

\additionalInfo{I am additional}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

One possibility is the `multiaudience` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multiaudience}
\SetNewAudience{long}
% remove comment from the following line for the long version
%\DefCurrentAudience{long}

\begin{document}

normal text
\begin{shownto}{long}
   Text for execs
\end{shownto}
normal text 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `ifthen` package to implement this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{somevariable}
\setboolean{somevariable}{false}

\begin{document}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{somevariable}}{Text if somevariable is true.}{Text if somevariable is false.}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I usually do this using new `if`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifprintsolution
\printsolutiontrue
\begin{document}
Assignment.

\ifprintsolution
Solution.
\fi
\end{document}
```

See e.g. https://www.bersling.com/2016/05/22/programming-in-latex/

Answer (score 1):

An approach using the `version` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{version}
%\excludeversion{foo}
\includeversion{foo}

\begin{document}

all versions

\begin{foo}
only in version foo
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```